# Can we migrate Teradata to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Can we migrate Teradata to Amazon DynamoDB?

Say for example I have table_1 in Teradata, I need to create the same table table_1 in DynamoDB, and I need to move the data from Teradata `table_1` to dynamodb `table_1`. Is this something I can achieve?

Say I have this below table in Teradata. Can I create this in DynamoDB and can I move the data from Teradata to DynamoDB?

```
CREATE SET TABLE FDM_TABLES_DB.OA3NF_CUSTOMER ,
NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      CUSTOMER_ID DECIMAL(18,0) NOT NULL,
      CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(360) CHARACTER SET LATIN CASESPECIFIC,
      CUSTOMER_TYPE_CD VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      OA_LAST_UPDATE_DTTM TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DDHH:MI:SS',
      OA_YEAR_ESTABLISHED DECIMAL(4,0),
      OA_CUSTOMER_STATUS_CD VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET LATIN CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      OA_CUST_FISCAL_YEAREND_MONTH VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN CASESPECIFIC,
      CUSTOMER_NUMBER VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN CASESPECIFIC)
PRIMARY INDEX OA3NF_CUSTOMER_1 ( CUSTOMER_ID );
```

We did a CBS (Columbia Broadcast System) project before.

In this project we migrated the data from Oracle to Teradata using Informatica PowerCenter. The client is now looking to move the data to AWS and my manager is asking me to check whether we can migrate the data from Teradata to DynamoDB? If yes how we can achieve it?

For example, I have 3 tables in Teradata:

1. Customer under customer we have below columns

   - Customer_id, customer_name
2. Product under product we have below columns

   - product_id, product_name, customer_name

3.address under address table we have below columns

- customer_id, customer_address, customer_name

With the help of customer_ID or Customer_name I can fetch the data from all the three tables at a time.

You are saying we cannot achieve this in DynamoDB because it is NoSQL database. So, if I want to fetch the data from all the three tables in DynamoDB what do I need to do?

Based upon the project we developed we have dimension tables and fact tables if we want to load the data from Teradata how we need to load it to DynamoDB is my question is this possible or not?

And fortunately we need reports too.

Comment: You probably want to load this into Redshift, no?

Comment: Yes,Team is working on it @Henry, but  my task is to  look for a second option that can achieve it with dynamodb.

Comment: Thats like asking for an alternative to the aircraft, but involving a bicycle. It simply isnt viable. yes, you technically CAN have your data warehouse in DynamoDB, but you arent remotely structured for it. The non-Redshift alternative would be Athena, EMR/Hive, and potentially at a stretch EMR/Hive on DynamoDB.

Comment: thank you very much for ur reply @henry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon DynamoDB is a NoSQL database.

While you could definitely migrate the data to DynamoDB, you would not be able to run SQL commands against DynamoDB.

Traditionally, SQL databases (eg Teradata) are used for reporting. It's a great way to churn through lots of data with simple commands. However, queries can take time, ranging from seconds to minutes.

A NoSQL database, such as DynamoDB, does not accept SQL. It is typically accessed programmatically. The benefit, however, is that it is highly scalable and can offer guaranteed query speed -- but the queries are simply Get/Put rather than complex queries.

So... Yes, you can migrate it. But whether you wish to do so depends on your use-case.

Comment: thank you for your response @john Rotenstein,  need small help.. i have few more questions kindly answer me , that will help me a lot..

Comment: 1.so we can migrate teradata  to dynamodb can you explain me with small example how we can migrate 2. which tool we need to prefer to migrate the data from teradata to dynamo db 3. do joins exist in dynamodb...? if no,how we need to define relation between one table to another table ?say i have "customer" table and "product" table so can i fetch data from both tables in dynamodb like how i can get in sql?

Comment: SQL databases are *relational databases*. Amazon DynamoDB is *not* a relational database. Therefore, you cannot define relations between tables and you can only access data from one table at a time. Can I ask... why are you considering migrating to DynamoDB? Can you tell us more about your use-case? (Feel free to Edit the question to add details, rather than adding it as a comment.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses @jhon Rotenstein i added few more question kindly look into that

Comment: You cannot use DynamoDB for the tasks you listed. You should tell your manager that DynamoDB is not a suitable option. If you are looking for a Data Warehouse, use Amazon Redshift.

Comment: Thanks for your response,do joins exist in dynamodb..? is there any concept like fact and dimension in dynamodb..? @jhon Rotenstein

Comment: No, there's are no JOINs in DynamoDB. There are no concepts like Facts and Dimensions.

Comment: Thank u very much @Jhon Rotenstein. If I want to give feedback for u ,how i need to give?

Comment: You have already accepted my answer. That is fine, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately not. StackOverflow is a site for answering programming-related technical questions.